# Create and use a new ttk::notebook tab style

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I know we can modify the default style of a ttk::notebook tab using the following method :

```
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab -background red
```

My question is : **is it possible to assign a custom style to individual tabs?** Bascially, I would like something like this :

```
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab.Red -background red
ttk::style configure TNotebook.Tab.Green -background green

ttk::notebook .main.notebook
.main.notebook add .main.notebook.tab1 -text "I am red" -style TNotebook.Tab.Red
.main.notebook add .main.notebook.tab2 -text "I am green" -style TNotebook.Tab.Green
```

However, notebook tab options doesn't include a `-style` option. So is this possible?

Comment: Good question. I suspect that you can't do it, but I don't know…

Comment: Since tabs obviously have their own styling already, wouldn't it be an "easy" feature to add?

Comment: There was recently another request for tab styling, and even though it was a better use-case than yours, someone has to make the changes, or be convinced to make the changes.  https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=2782346

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. There are no hooks and no accessible widgets you can choose to style tabs individually. The best you can do is use compound labels with images to give a little flare to the tabs.